Forbid input to TextBox symbol "[" (square bracket)
The application of Windows form (Desktop). There is a TextBox. Need allow input here any unicode symbols except "[".
On the physical QWERTY keyboard, the key responsible for entering the symbol "[" when the English layout is turned on is the Cyrillic "x" symbol, if you choose the Ukrainian layout.
It is necessary to prohibit the printing of the symbol "[" (with the English layout), but allow the printing of the symbol "x"(Cyrillic) (with the Ukrainian layout) or symbol "{".
part of QWERTY keyboard
I tried catching the KeyDown event to determine which character is being entered into the text field using the following code:
Dim Converter = New System.Windows.Forms.KeysConverter
Dim keyChar As Object = Converter.ConvertToString(e.KeyCode)


Unfortunately keyChar = "OemOpenBrackets" instead "[" (for English layout) or "x" (for Ukrainian laout)

Looks like on event KeyPress possible to forbid the input "[":
If CInt(AscW(e.KeyChar)) = 91 Then
e.Handled = True
Return
End If
